# variable not displaying in output?

Tags: php

I perform the following..

```
$output = $_GET['_url'];
echo $output;
//displays the url in $output, correctly

if ( isset($_POST['email'])){
//'email' is not empty

echo "url: " . $output;
//it displays "url: " but does not display the url from $output
}
```

I enter an email and on submit it does not echo the $output var during the if post.. only outside of it.

Why is this the case and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It is not possible for the code you've provided.

Comment: Maybe you meant `echo "url: " . $_POST['email']`?

Comment: By the way, why not put the variable right in the quote? As in, echo "url: $output";

Comment: @zerkms: is there another way? @Jon: Nope :) Once the user posts the email, I want to use the URL after some try/catch. @crimson_penguin: You're right, I should!

Comment: Figured it out.  He's calling the script **alternately** as a get and a post.  When he calls it as a get, he sees the url correctly.  When he calls it as a post, he sees `url:` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing $_GET and $_POST.

Try adding:

```
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
```

and see what you get.  That should help you figure out what's happening

Comment: Your question was, "What can I do to fix it?"  My answer is to add a couple of `var_dump`s (or `print_r`s if you prefer) so that you know for sure what's in your `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays.  Once you know this, fixing the problem will be trivial.

Comment: @awm: I made my comment when there was nothing about var_dumps

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, I carelessly assumed your comment came from the person who asked the question, and it obviously didn't. :(  My comment above was intended for DT85.

Comment: @awm: Before post, $_GET has 7 chars and is displayed in the dump., whereas $_POST is empty. After $_POST, $_POST has the email address in it and $_GET is empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "before post" and "after post"?

Comment: @awm: Before the email is submitted (posted).. I think ajax is playing up so once removed it seems to go through using GET and POST. Strange!

Comment: You mean you're calling the script more than once an expecting variables to be preserved?!?  Sorry, I give up.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mixing GET and POST requests. Is the request GET or POST? It can't be both!

**Edit:** it can, but still, check if your form is sent as GET or POST and update the variables accordingly. Unless you do POST request to url like someurl?var=something.

Comment: The request cannot be, but superglobals are filled according to the data source. So you can send POST request with some post data in the data body and pass some parameters though the url. So in that case in php you'll have both $_POST and $_GET variables.

Comment: That will be interesting. Even though both variable may be set soehow, how do you do it? Is there a way how to perform both HTTP GET and POST request in one? Hope you don't mean POST request to url like someurl?request=whatever? Just curious, not saying I know it best

Comment: @Jan Zyka: I meant exactly sending POST request using `file?param=value` url

Comment: Well ... you believe this is his case? :) I bet a beer he mixed unintentionaly GET and POST

Comment: @Jan Zyka: well, you can ask by email my address to send me beer right after you'll have tested it ;-)

Comment: @Jan Zyka: anyway, look again at his code: he tries to output the `$output` variable which **is not blank** as he has written on the 3rd line. I can't think of any possible scenario when `$output` become blank in such code.

Comment: He enters the email ... where? I believe in a form which is sent as GET. So he get displayed the `output` when it is without a condition but not in the second case. Because only $_GET['email'] is set, not $_POST['email'] :) (Maybe)

Comment: @Jan Zyka: 1. he sees "url: " --- this means he has $_POST['email'] exists. 2. He sees url from the 2nd line of the code - so there is something in the $_GET['_url'] and `$output` 3. if items 1 and 2 happens in one script and there is nothing between those parts as it is in the question - then there is no any possibility for the scenario OP has described ;-)

Comment: @Jan Zyka: comment from the 2nd line in the bottom

Comment: @Jan Zyka, @zerkms: The `$_GET['_url']` is from htaccess redirect `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: Still didn't get it. HE says he doesn't see `output`, say nothing about what he DOES see. Never mind. If it's like you wrote it's nonsense. Can't be as you wrote. If it is mine, still can be solution. Giving up :)

Comment: @DT85: it doesn't matter where it came from. The code you've given us cannot behave in the way you've described.

Comment: @Jan Zyka " //**it displays** "url: " but does not display the url from $output " --- well, he wrote that he does see it ;-)

Comment: My bad I'am filtering out impossible scenarios at first :)

Comment: @zerkms: What is the best workaround for it? Store the $_GET in the DB and pull it out when I need to use it?

Comment: @zerkms: What about a hidden field in the form which stores the value of $_GET and passed through $_POST? Just need to work out a way I can use the data in $_GET during a $_POST. Thanks!

Comment: @DT85 zerkms hit the nail on the head.  "It doesn't matter where it came from..."  Read very, very carefully! :)

Comment: @awm: Understood ;) I'm starting to see the light now hehe figuring it out I think :)